# Pyramid pattern using java with number

Tags: java

How to write a java program to print below the pattern?

```
    1
   2 2
  3   3
   2 2
    1
```

Comment: Try something on your own first, and then ask what your problem exactly is

Comment: Step 1) Don't be so lazy. Programming will not be for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment..Next time i ll post a good question with exact code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what are you looking for:

```
System.out.println("\t   1\n\t 2   2\n\t3     3\n\t 2   2\n\t   1  ");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer....any logic behind this? if we write this in nested for loop ll it be possible or not..

Comment: @DurgaPrasadsahu no, this is not the right way to do that, because if you want a pyramid with many more numbers you will have a lot of pain. You need to develop some logic with a for loop, try to show some code, i'm sure that we will help you!

Comment: class Pyramid {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <4; i += 2) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3 - i / 2; j++)
        System.out.print(" ");

      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        System.out.print(j+1);

      System.out.print("\n");
    }

    for (int i = 1; i > 0; i -= 2) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3 - i / 2; j++)
        System.out.print(" ");

      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        System.out.print(j+1);

      System.out.print("\n");
    }
  }
}

Comment: @DurgaPrasadsahu you could post the code on your question :) it's more readable ;)